# How to limit slicer selection to one

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I wish to limit user selection of slicer to one. Tried this code but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, _
   ByVal Target As PivotTable)
'--when pivot update event triggered, checks whether a specified slicer
'    has more than one item selected.
'  If so, user is warned and optionally the last action can be undone

 Dim bSlicerIsConnected As Boolean
 Dim pvt As PivotTable
 Dim slc As SlicerCache
 Dim sLastUndoStackItem  As String

 '--modify this to match your slicer's name
 Const sSLICER_NAME As String =  "SlicerName"

 sLastUndoStackItem = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)

 '--validate event was triggered by slicer or filter, not other pivot operation
 Select Case sLastUndoStackItem
   Case "Slicer Operation", "Filter"
      'continue
   Case Else
      'do nothing and exit
      GoTo ExitProc
 End Select

 '--validate specified slicer exists
 On Error Resume Next
 Set slc = SlicerCaches(sSLICER_NAME)
 On Error GoTo 0

 If slc Is Nothing Then
   GoTo ExitProc
 End If

 '--validate pvt that triggered event is connected to specified slicer
 For Each pvt In slc.PivotTables
   If pvt.Name = Target.Name Then
      bSlicerIsConnected = True
      Exit For
   End If
 Next pvt

 '--test how many items selected and take action if more than one
 If bSlicerIsConnected Then
   If slc.VisibleSlicerItems.Count > 1 Then
      '--option a: only warn user
      'MsgBox "Only one item may be selected" & vbCr _
      '  & "Please undo last selection."

      '--option b: warn user and undo
      MsgBox "Only one item may be selected"
      With Application
         .EnableEvents = False
         .Undo
      End With
   End If
 End If
ExitProc:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue.... and came up with a non techy solution that works for me. I inserted a shape to hide the multi-select and clear filter buttons on the slicer. Just a white rectangle that I sized just right. I protect the worksheet anyway so the shape cannot move and it is not visible to the user. So simple but works.